# HTML ID with numerical value not recognized by CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is the div:

```
<div class='something' id='1'>
```

I got 9 of them with different positions on page so in the `.css` file I do:

```
div#1.something {
  code...
}
```

And the thing is that it won't work, I know this is the proper selector but I have also tried `div.something#1` and it also doesn't work, as expected. I think there is something wrong with ID as a number, should I change it or there is a way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although it's allowed to set a `class` or `id` to begin with a digit in HTML5, but it's not allowed in CSS, see the spec:

[HTML5: 3.2.5.1 The id attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

> ... There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, **start with a digit**, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc. ...

---

[CSS: 4.1.3 Characters and case](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)

> ... they **cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code ...

i.e.

`<div id="1">` is valid HTML, but you cannot target it with `#1 {...}` in CSS.

However, you can use `[id="1"] {...}` or escape it `#\31 {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

You can call either by class or ID.

```
div.something {
code...
}
```

or

```
div#1 {
code...
}
```

Comment: It would work but I can't make any others div with IDs as numbers but thanks, have an upvote.

Comment: I mean - second one will not work as CSS won't accept number as beginning of ID.

Answer (score -1):

Change `id="1"` to `id="one"` since you cannot use numbers in CSS to select an id or class. Then just use `div#one { // CSS Here }` since you don't really need to include the class. After all you can only have one `id` with a specific name per page.